# What is the environmentally safe way to guard the vegetable and fruit plants from squirrels?

Tags: protection

The squirrels are eating our strawberries :( We lost couple of our corn plants which were growing really well to the squirrels. Is there any safe way to keep them at bay?

Comment: Have you actually seen squirrels eating your plants?  It really isn't their thing!  I deal with bunnies and have wire fencing all around my garden.  Works just fine and I have (dumb me) promoted a huge herd of bunnies.  Squirrels...never have seen them eating plants.  Go buy a huge bag of peanuts and dump it away from the garden.  You have to make a little fence at any rate and it is cheap and easy peasy to do.  Then there are the deer...

Comment: @stormy: Yes I did see the squirrels eating the plant. One of the corn plants was nearly 2 feet tall. It was the tallest of the 6 we planted. The animal just gnawed it off at the base and was munching on the stem sitting on the backyard fence :(

Comment: Welp I stand corrected, grins.  Squirrels must be starving I think to go that far.  At this point I would buy that bag of peanuts...dump away from your garden.  There is no way that squirrels would prefer vegetables to protein stuffed nuts.  I know squirrels.  Is this in an urban, suburban development?  Amazing...how many of your corn plants did they consume?  One?  15?  When my bunnies actually find the gate not closed...they do not do much damage...even bunnies that LOVE VEGEYS.  In one night.  Never have had problems with squirrels and I kinda promote wildlife...arghhhhhh!